# Magento 1: Move Domains to subfolder

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess

I have a multi-store setup with the german domain running on .de and the english on .com.

Now I need to move them both together to the .com domain utilizing the store codes in the urls.

```
www.example.de -> www.example.com/de/
www.example.com -> www.example.com/en/
```

The magento setup itself runs fine. What I have issues with is to redirect the existing urls (from google) to their new location:

```
www.example.de/category.html -> www.example.com/de/category.html
www.example.com/category.html -> www.example.com/en/category.html
```

So I setup a simple test site (not magento) only to create the proper htaccess rewrite rules. This is what I figured out and it works as expected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !de/
RewriteRule (.*) /de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/
RewriteRule (.*) /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I put this into my magento .htaccess things get weird though.

Of course there are more magento specific rewrites in there. The complete list of rules are these:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !de/
RewriteRule (.*) /de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/
RewriteRule (.*) /en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Those extra rules are all from a default magento installation.

When I access https://www.example.com I end up at https://www.example.com/en/index.php with a browser error (endless redirect).

How to get this right?

Thank you